# Create XML file using c# like below format

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to create xml using c# below format.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <AddressLine1 xmlns="">50 W TOWN ST</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2 xmlns="">STE 400</AddressLine2>
        <City xmlns="">COLUMBUS</City>
        <State xmlns="">OH</State>
        <Zip xmlns="">43215</Zip>
        <Zip4 xmlns=""/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Below is my c# code to create xml like above

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateElement("SOAP-ENV:Envelope");
        XmlAttribute typeAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:SOAP-ENV");
        typeAttr.Value = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        docNode.Attributes.Append(typeAttr);
        doc.AppendChild(docNode);

        XmlNode AddressRequestBody = doc.CreateElement("SOAP-ENV:Body");
        docNode.AppendChild(AddressRequestBody);

        ........
        ........

        XmlNode Zip4Node = doc.CreateElement("Zip4");
        typeAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
        typeAttr.Value = "";
        Zip4Node.Attributes.Append(typeAttr);
        Zip4Node.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(""));
        AddressRequestBody.AppendChild(Zip4Node);
```

With the above code I am geting xml like below. missing ***SOAP-ENV:*** in Envelop and body tags. Any idea to how to get SOAP-ENV: in both Envelop and body tags. I am new to xml not sure how to get.

```
<Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <Body>
  <AddressLine1 xmlns="">Add1</AddressLine1>
  <AddressLine2 xmlns="">Add2</AddressLine2>
  <City xmlns="">City1</City>
  <State xmlns="">state1</State>
  <Zip xmlns="">zip1</Zip>
  <Zip4 xmlns=""></Zip4>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: You should use `XElement`.

Comment: Your XML is invalid; an XML document must have exactly one root.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [This document already has a ' DocumentElement ' node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6262815/3744182).  Is that a sufficient answer for your question?

Comment: dbc, i got the answer but my xml coming like <Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">. how can i get output like <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">.                                SOAP-ENV: is missing

Comment: @VenkatKrishna - you may need to [edit] your question and add a [mcve] demonstrating the new problem.  I'm not quite sure what your second issue is just from your comment.

Comment: dbc, I have edited question. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your required XML using the [XML Document Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-document-object-model-dom) as follows:

```
var soapNs = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
var bodyNs = @"";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
var root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("SOAP-ENV", "Envelope", soapNs));
var body = root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("SOAP-ENV", "Body", soapNs));

body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "AddressLine1", bodyNs)).InnerText = "50 W TOWN ST";
body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "AddressLine2", bodyNs)).InnerText = "STE 400";
body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "City", bodyNs)).InnerText = "COLUMBUS";
body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "State", bodyNs)).InnerText = "OH";
body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "Zip", bodyNs)).InnerText = "43215";
body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "Zip4", bodyNs)).InnerText = "";
```

Using this approach, the following XML is generated:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <AddressLine1>50 W TOWN ST</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>STE 400</AddressLine2>
    <City>COLUMBUS</City>
    <State>OH</State>
    <Zip>43215</Zip>
    <Zip4></Zip4>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Notes:

1. A well-formed XML document must have one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  In the initial version of your question, you try to add multiple nodes directly to the `XmlDocument doc`:

   ```
   doc.AppendChild(docNode);
   // Snip some code  
   doc.AppendChild(AddressRequestNode);
   ```

   Attempting to do this causes the `This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.` exception to be thrown.
2. Your XML document has elements in two namespaces: `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` and the empty namespace.  In situations such as this, it's easiest to use the [`XmlDocument.CreateElement(string prefix, string localName, string namespaceURI)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c22k3d47.aspx) API and always explicitly specify the namespace URI, rather than simply specifying the namespace lookup prefix and hoping you had correctly initialized the corresponding `xmlns:` prefix value earlier.

   In the sample XML, the `Envelope` and `Body` nodes are in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace while their child nodes are in the empty namespace, which is what is reflected in my sample code.
3. [`XmlNode.AppendChild(XmlNode)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx) returns the appended child and so can be used in a fluent style.
4. In the sample XML the innermost elements are explicitly specified to have a default namespace of `""`:

   ```
   <AddressLine1 xmlns="">50 W TOWN ST</AddressLine1>
   ```

   Actually the `xmlns=""` is unnecessary because there is no default namespace specified at a higher level in the XML.  Thus the following is semantically identical and sufficient:

   ```
   <AddressLine1>50 W TOWN ST</AddressLine1>
   ```

   If for some reason you are **required** to have this redundant namespace declaration, you can do:

   ```
   var line1 = body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("", "AddressLine1", bodyNs));
   line1.Attributes.Append(doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns")).Value = bodyNs;
   line1.InnerText = "50 W TOWN ST";
   ```

   Which results in

   ```
   <AddressLine1 xmlns="">50 W TOWN ST</AddressLine1>
   ```
5. [`XmlElement.InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx) can be used to set the text value of a element with no child elements.  This is more succinct than calling `CreateTextNode()` then appending the result to the DOM.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o3UCkO).